# Indexing Fact table - suggestions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, olap, olap-cube

Alright, my fact table is about 40m rows big and has a total of 6 foreign key columns and one timestamp column.

Three Dimensionsens are 100.000 to 200.000 (i.e. Customer) rows big, one ~20.000 and the other two ~3.000.

Now I am looking on a good way for indexing my star schema. At the moment I got B-tree indexes on the primary keys of the dimensions. I was thinking about using bitmap joins on the smaller dimensions. But what about the bigger ones? And how would I use the bitmap join. Would I use the primary key column and another attribute (i.e. country) from the dimension or just the primary key?

When using bitmap joins, is it good to use normal bitmap indexes on the FK in the fact table too?

Comment: Be careful on using bitmap indexes on frequently modified tables.

Comment: well because the fact/dimensions will be loaded daily, I would have droped / recreated the index before/after each load.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "And how would I use the bitmap join. Would I use the primary key column and another attribute (i.e. country) from the dimension or just the primary key?"? Do you mean, should you create a bitmap join index that indexes the primary key of the dimension table?

Comment: Indeed. If I remember correctly, some whitepapers suggested using the bitmap join index on primary keys of the dimension .... but thats not pretty wise, right?